# What is the role of .eh_frame segment

Tags: c, gcc

When I use `gcc` to compile a C language program using

```
readelf  -h filename
```

to view the file segment, there is a `.Eh_frame`.

What is this segment doing?

Comment: For unwinding and exception handling?

Answer (score 4):

When gcc generates certain code that handles exceptions, it would produce tables that could describe how to unwind the stack. These tables are found in the .eh_frame section. eh=exception handling. The .eh_frame, contains exception unwinding and source language information wherein, each entry in is represented by a single CFI.

For more information see: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/ehframechpt.html